# How to get the output parameter as the response in python

Tags: python, sql-server, django

I'm trying to get the list of user's based whose name starts based on the typing the name from the SQL database.

In SQL there is an output parameter in which I want to return as API response.
Whenever I type the name 'R' it just returning only one character in the output but I want to return the entire name

views.py:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def FetchSuggestionAuditAgent(request):
    if request.method =='POST':
        agents = request.data.get('Agents')

        sql = """\
        DECLARE @response NVARCHAR;
        EXEC dbo.FetchSuggestionAuditAgent @agents = %s, @response = @response OUTPUT;
        SELECT @response AS out_value;
        """
        params = (agents,)
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute(sql, params)
        result_set = cursor.fetchall()
        print(result_set)

        for row in result_set:
          agents = row[0]
        return Response({'Agents':agents})
```

SQL SP:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_FetchSuggestionAuditAgent] -- 'apolonia ',''  

 @agents nvarchar(max),@response nvarchar(1000) OUTPUT        
AS      
BEGIN      

  set @agents = LTRIM(RTRIM(@agents))
   
 select top 1 @response = FullName from tblusers where FullName like '%'+@agents+'%'   
 and isactive =1    and IsDeleted = 0
  order by FullName desc     

      
END
```

Comment: FYI the prefix `sp_` is reserved, by Microsoft, for **S**pecial / **S**ystem **P**rocedures. It should *not* be used for User Procedures. Doing so comes with a performance cost and the risk of your Procedure simply not working one day after an update/upgrade. Either use a different prefix or (possibly better) no prefix at all. [Is the sp_ prefix still a no-no?](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix)

Comment: You need to define the length of your `nvarchar` parameter: `... DECLARE @response NVARCHAR(1000) ...`